# Why endpoints-proto-datastore is not part of official google endpoints documentation?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/

Is it reliable to use endpoints proto datastore library even if its not officially documented in google endpoints documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It's an extension to Google Endpoints to make life easier of Python programmers provided by Googlers.

The fact that it's not documented in the official Google Cloud documentation doesn't mean is not reliable. I'd use it without a doubt if I met the restriction stated:

> The Endpoints Proto Datastore API currently *supports only NDB classes*.